# How well-known is the term 리즈 시절 ("Leeds season")?

Tags: idiom, slang

[This BBC article](https://www.bbc.co.uk/bbcthree/article/68c9c99d-c9d8-4857-96dd-b10336e2118e) defines the Korean understanding of this as:

> You refer to someone’s ‘Leeds season’ as the point in their life where things peaked, before going downhill.

I can find other references to it - e.g. [https://namu.wiki/w/리즈%20시절](https://namu.wiki/w/%EB%A6%AC%EC%A6%88%20%EC%8B%9C%EC%A0%88).

But is it well known in 2019 - either among football fans, or among the wider Korean population?

Comment: I have seen people on DC Inside refer to actresses having a "Leeds season" as well. Never heard this term used outside of Korea, though.

Answer (score 3):

A criterion for that is Naver News or other Internet news sites. 리즈 시절 was mentioned as a newly-coined word in [an 2010 news article](https://sports.news.naver.com/general/news/read.nhn?oid=020&aid=0002104770) and is still used. Its relevant term, 리즈 갱신, seems to have been used since [2012](https://entertain.naver.com/read?oid=082&aid=0000350646). This indicates that it is highly likely for the populace to have seen or heard these two terms.

There are a wide variety of Korean videos on YouTube. Some of them have [리즈 시절](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=%EB%A6%AC%EC%A6%88+%EC%8B%9C%EC%A0%88) and [리즈 갱신](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=%EB%A6%AC%EC%A6%88+%EA%B0%B1%EC%8B%A0) in their titles. As a lot of people enjoy watching YouTube videos today, you can easily find that these terms are widely used.

Answer (score 0):

I'm 25 here (Korean-age), I think it's totally okay to use it unless the opponent is too old.

Even news writers use this word every day, you can find it here:
https://search.naver.com/search.naver?&where=news&query=%EB%A6%AC%EC%A6%88%EC%8B%9C%EC%A0%88&sm=tab_tmr&frm=mr&nso=so:r,p:all,a:all&sort=0
http://www.joongdo.co.kr/main/view.php?key=20190625001103523

You may notice that the word is not limited to football fans, it's widely used.